# How to install .Net 3.5 and 4.0 together?

Tags: .net, installation, nsis, silent

I'm creating installer for one my application. This installer need to install .Net framwork as dependency.

The problem i have is, i could not find single installer which install maximum upto 4.0 framework.

Iy you look at .Net 3.5 installer it does 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 and finally 3.5 (It is incremental installer)

I couldn't find samething for 4.0 installer. I understand this is not availble.

But i'm looking for a solution how to install 3.5 and 4.0 using single installer?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check for, and install, both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.  The official .NET 4.0 installer from Microsoft is just that: .NET 4.0.  Both of these can easily be done by checking the Registry for the existence of .NET 3.5 (you can also check for .NET 3.5 SP1 if your app requires it) as well as .NET 4.0.  Your installer can query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\ for the following:

v3.5 - .NET 3.5 exists (look for a REG_DWORD of SP - if that equals 1 then you also have .NET 3.5 SP1)

v4 (not to be confused with v4.0) - .NET 4.0 exists.  You can drill down further to see if there is Client or Full, for the Client Profile and the full installation, respectively.

You can use the NSISdl plugin to grab the installers from the Microsoft website.  When you get to the "Thank-you for Downloading" page, you will see a "if your download doesn't begin after 30 seconds" link.  That link is the one you will use for NSISdl.

.NET 3.5 SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22 (this includes .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0, .NET 3.5, and .NET 3.5 SP1)
.NET 4.0 Full: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718 (this includes .NET 4.0 only)

For an example of how I implemented grabbing the .NET Framework version 4.5 (yes I know you need a different version), have a look at my entry in the NSIS Wiki: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download_and_Install_dotNET_45

This takes care of being able to download from the Microsoft website, or (for CD/DVD/USB distributions) including the .NET Framework installer with your own installer.

If you have any other questions, please reply and I'll be glad to help.

---

NOTE: On Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, the first time Windows detects that an app wants .NET 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5: Windows will grab a special installation off of Windows Update.  There is no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> ".NET 4.0 adds in-process side-by-side compatibility with earlier
>   versions of the Framework. This feature allows an application process
>   to simultaneously run part of its code using the .NET Common Language
>   Runtime (CLR) 4 and other parts using older versions of the CLR."

Also check

- [How to: Upgrade an ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478%28VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Can you have both .Net Framework 3.5 and 4.0 on 64-bit Windows 7
  ?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/can-you-have-both-net-framework-35-and-40-on-64/fd4511fe-54ba-4f24-8148-98d5e64b6aa2)
- [.Net 4.0 installation, does this include install of .Net 3.5 SP
  1?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a24b92cc-ab5a-481f-b759-0899ccc68296/net-40-installation-does-this-include-install-of-net-35-sp-1)

Comment: My requirement is, i need to have both 3.5 and 4.0 installation exist before lauching the application.  Is there any installer which does 3.5 and 4.0 framework installation?